# GNU Make Recursive Directory Listing

Tags: gnu-make

Is there a way to get the directory path and the paths of all the subdirectories recursively using GNU make without explicitly writing

```
    dirpaths :=
    dirpaths +=$(wlidcard L0dir/*)
    dirpaths +=$(wlidcard L0dir/*/*)
```

and so on.

```
    L0dir
    ├── L1subdir1
    │   ├── L2subdir1
    │   ├── L2subdir2
    │   └── L2subdir3
    ├── L1subdir2
    │   └── L2subdir1
    ├── L1subdir3
    └── L1subdir4
```

The content of the variable $(dirpaths) should be :

```
    L0dir L0dir/L1subdir1 L0dir/L1subdir1/L2subdir1 L0dir/L1subdir1/L2subdir2 L0dir/L1subdir1/L2subdir3 L0dir/L1subdir2 L0dir/L1subdir2/L2subdir1 L0dir/L1subdir3 L0dir/L1subdir4
```

Comment: Can you use `$(shell find L0dir -print)` ?

Comment: OK, I will try this, thanks MadScientist.

Comment: this is my command `$(shell find P:\project -print)` and the output is this  :  `FIND: Parameter format not correct`

Comment: Also my OS is Windows 10 and I can not switch to an Unix/Linux based system.

Comment: That would have been useful information to put into the question...

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this:

```
recurse = $(foreach D,$1,$(wildcard $D/*) $(call recurse,$(patsubst %/.,%,$(wildcard $D/*/.))))

dirpaths := $(call recurse,$(DIR))
```

Comment: It did not work, output : `1 [main] make 17948 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to make.exe.stackdump`

Comment: `Exception: STATUS_STACK_OVERFLOW at rip=0010041FC56
rax=000000000037DF60 rbx=00000000005F8D50 rcx=0000000000403CD0
rdx=FEFF1F1F1F070100 rsi=00000000005F8D58 rdi=0000000100425EBA
r8 =FFFFDFDFDF97D198 r9 =8080808080808080 r10=FEFEFEFEFEFEFEFF
r11=000006FFF8C21F5F r12=00000006000C1830 r13=0000000000571F50
r14=000006FFF86B0010 r15=0000000000000001
rbp=00000000005F8CF0 rsp=00000000005F8CB8
program=P:\project\tools\bin\make.exe, pid 17948, thread main
cs=0033 ds=002B es=002B fs=0053 gs=002B ss=002B`

Comment: `Stack trace:
Frame        Function    Args
000005F8CF0  0010041FC56 (001004074B9, 00029736874, 0010041D539, 00600063FD0)
000005F8CF0  00000571F60 (001004074B9, 00029736874, 0010041D539, 00600063FD0)
End of stack trace`

Comment: I am sorry I am fairly new to stackoverflow so I could not fit the entire message in one comment

Comment: Looks like you have either a bug in your version of GNU make, or your directory structure is too large to fit into make's memory.  It worked for me on my Linux system; I don't use Windows.  If you add an `info` command, like `recurse = $(info ARG=$1)$(foreach ....)` and run it, does it seem to be infinitely looping?  You won't be able to paste the output so you'll just have to see for yourself if it looks OK or not.

Comment: Thank you for your help and I would like to ask, should GNU Make be used for Windows or should it only be used with Unix/Linux based systems? If it shouldn't be used with Windows, what should I use instead?

Comment: Also is the `$(shell )` function supposed to work on a Windows operating system?

Comment: GNU make itself is portable.  Many people use it on Windows and there are no good (IMO) direct alternatives on Windows.  Windows has nmake but it's quite limited.  You can instead switch to something like CMake which is a "meta build tool", in that you define your build then use CMake to generate actual build control files.  So it can generate makefiles, Visual Studio project files, and various other types of output.

Comment: Yes, `$(shell ...)` works on Windows.  The problem is not related to GNU make, the problem is related to the commands that GNU make invokes.  The `$(shell ...)` function runs command line programs on your system.  On a POSIX-based system like Linux or MacOS, there are lots of command line tools and they're all designed to work together, and they are covered by a standard (POSIX) that lets you use `$(shell ...)` to invoke them in a portable way.  Windows has a completely different set of command line tools, so you can use `$(shell ...)` but you can only run Windows tools, which are different.

Comment: what are the tools that I should try to use with windows to list all the subdirectories in the desired folder?

Comment: I don't know.  I don't ever use Windows.  If you want to ask that you probably should ask a new question and be sure to tag it with a proper Windows tag.  But, I first recommend using The Google because I'm sure this question is quite simple for you to answer yourself, without having to ask on SO.